# Internal Server Error when upgrading from django 1.9 to django 1.11

Tags: django, django-urls, url-pattern, django-1.9, django-1.11

I have upgraded from django 1.9 to django 1.11.

As I run `python manage.py runserver` after the upgrade I got an error due to the import of `patterns`. I realised it made sense, since `patterns` is depracted.

So I changed my `urls.py` from

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

to

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]
```

By running `python manage.py runserver` it works just fine, but when pushing it to Heroku, the website shows and Internal Server Error.

And I receive this message:

```
Internal Server Error: /

TypeError at /
view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

By just removing the `if not settings.DEBUG` part, the website from the server loads without Internal Server Error, but there is no CSS.

Any idea of what is causing the error?

---

### Solution

Unfortunately, as it is marked as duplicated I cannot post the solution, so I explain it here hoping it can help others who face the same issue:

1) As explained in the other question, hardcoding urls is not allowed in the newer versions of Django. So the hardcoding here was causing the error.

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Once removed, no CSS was found. Here comes the step number 2:

2) Installing [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html), as proposed in the comments.

I just had to install it: `pip install whitenoise`. Then add it into the `requirements.txt` file and follow the few steps explained in their site.

Comment: post your view which s getting rendered at / ? and also if there is any base.html you are using

Comment: I don't think you should have that `if not settings.DEBUG:` block at all - `django.static.views.serve` should only be used in DEBUG mode. If you remove that block, it should stop the error. If you must include the block, then use `static()` or import the view [as in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development). You could look at [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to serve your static files properly.

Comment: @Alasdair , by removing the block I do not get any CSS... I'll have a look now at the question mention

Comment: The duplicate question and the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development) explain how to fix the error, but as I said you shouldn't be using `serve` in production. Look at [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) instead.

Comment: @Alasdair , I don't see why is this question a duplicated, as in the other question the problem was the hardcoding of the views in the urls. This is not the problem I have... Concerning WhiteNoise, is there not a way to get the CSS in Heroku without having to use an non-native Django settings?

Comment: Your problem is an exact duplicate. You have hardcoded `'django.views.static.serve'` in the url. You don't have to use WhiteNoise (e.g. you could host the static files on a CDN), but you should not use `serve` in production.

Comment: My problem is for the url to the static files, not for a view to render a page itself. By following the solution suggested there, I know what is causing the Internal Error, but my problem is not solved. Thanks for the tips anyway.